# Why do I need to include a filter on value in pivot_longer() in tidyverse?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

So I have some data as follows:

```
id  A   B   C   D   fruit   word
1   1   0   0   0   apple   a
2   0   1   0   0   banana  a
3   1   0   0   0   apple   a
4   0   0   0   1   grape   v
5   0   0   0   1   grape   v
```

You can see it as follows:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), A = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0), B = c(0, 
1, 0, 0, 0), C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), D = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1), fruit = c("apple", 
"banana", "apple", "grape", "grape"), word = c("a", "a", "a", 
"v", "v")), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

And all I want to do is make the data tidy. I do so as follows:

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "treatment", 
               cols = c(A, B, C, D)) %>% 
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  select(-value)
```

And this does result in what I want:

```
     id fruit  word  treatment
1     1 apple  a     A             
2     2 banana a     B             
3     3 apple  a     A             
4     4 grape  v     D             
5     5 grape  v     D
```

But this only works because I add the `filter(value == 1)`. Why do I need this? Is there a way to get the same result by never involving `value` at all?

An ideal solution would be without ever even mentioning `value`, so removing the last two lines of the code. But if this is not possible, I want to understand what is happening here that makes the data **quadruple** without that code.

Here is what it looks like without those two lines.

```
      id fruit  word  treatment     value
 1     1 apple  a     A             1
 2     1 apple  a     B             0
 3     1 apple  a     C             0
 4     1 apple  a     D             0
 5     2 banana a     A             0
 6     2 banana a     B             1
 7     2 banana a     C             0
 8     2 banana a     D             0
 9     3 apple  a     A             1
10     3 apple  a     B             0
11     3 apple  a     C             0
12     3 apple  a     D             0
13     4 grape  v     A             0
14     4 grape  v     B             0
15     4 grape  v     C             0
16     4 grape  v     D             1
17     5 grape  v     A             0
18     5 grape  v     B             0
19     5 grape  v     C             0
20     5 grape  v     D             1
```

Why does this happen???

Comment: I'm confused. Your original data includes the "0" entries as well. What makes you think they would just disappear when you reshape from wide to long? If you don't want them you need to remove them with `filter`.

Comment: Im not following what u mean by the "0" entries... @MauritsEvers. I am asking, in the bottom example, why does it quadruple the data when i pivot

Comment: Your original data has 0 entries in the A, B, C, D columns. Why do you think they would automatically disappear when reshaping? In other words, why do you think you shouldn't/wouldn't  need the `filter` step, if you only want to keep the 1 entries?

Comment: oh I see what u mean. So to represent the 0, it takes form in the value column

Comment: *"So to represent the 0, it takes form in the value column"* I don't understand what that means. You are reshaping from wide to long. Everything (so in this case the 0 and 1 entries) in the relevant columns get treated equally. That's what you see in the full output (without `filter`).

Comment: I am following now, everything is affected when u pivot like this. thus the filter is required

Comment: Great. Perhaps the following super minimal example is useful for understanding what's going on when reshaping: `pivot_longer(data.frame(A = c(1, 0), B = c(0, 1)), everything())
`.